# SQL: Get latest Payment from all customers?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

im using Mysql 5.1 and given a table payments with columns customerid,paymentdate i need the all customers latest payment.
so a table with entries

```
row, customerid, paymentdate
1    5           2011-03-01
2    5           2011-04-01
3    6           2011-01-01
4    7           2011-01-01
5    7           2011-02-01
```

should return rows 2,3,5
the query

```
select max(paymentdate),customerid from payments where customerid=5;
```

works which i tried to get into some kind of WHERE customer IN(...) but with no luck since it returns 2 columns not only 1

thanks

---

in the end the answers inspired me to find related information and solved the problem with
the following query (as described in an articles comment)

```
select * from (select * from payments order by paymentdate desc) as p group by customerid;
```

[same problem from mysql forum](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,250707,250707#msg-250707)
[solutions from a related mysql article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html)

Answer (score 6):

You should `group by` the customerid.

```
select max(paymentdate),customerid from payments group by customerid;
```

Answer (score -1):

Another approach:

```
Select paymentdate,customerid from payments group by customerid order by paymentdate DESC;
```

Or even:

```
Select distinct(customerid),paymentdate from payments order by paymentdate DESC;
```

Adding a DESC to order by causes the most recent dates to be returned first.

Comment: none of those queries return expected results - i think this is because the order of the entries in the table. maybe im wrong, but e.g. the first query groups by customerid and then order by paymentdate. since e.g. an old entry (old paymentdate) is before a new one, the old one gets grouped and then sorted, thus not working

Answer (score -1):

```
select max(payment_id),customer_id,payment_date from tbl_payment WHERE payment_type = "credit" GROUP by customer_id
```

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of @gabriele-petrioli's answer from 2011, which is already 10 years old at this point, and adds no value here.

Comment: Yeah, considering payment_type isn't even mentioned in the question, I'm inclined to agree.